# Изменение атрибута value для аннотации @SerializedName при десериализации с использованием библиотеки gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

Использую библиотеку retrofit2 для работы с API одного сайта, который предоставляет статистику игроков. В ответ на запрос приходит следующий JSON:

```
 {
        "status": "ok",
        "meta": {
            "count": 1
        },
        "data": {
            "453608": { //ОБРАТИТЕ ВНИМАНИЕ НА ID, ОНО ВСЕГДА РАЗНОЕ(В ЗАВИСИМОСТИ ОТ ТОГО, КОГО ИЩЕМ)
               "global_rating": 441,
               "statistics": {
                  "all": {
                       //СТАТИСТИКА ИГРОКА
                   }
               }
            }
        }
  }
```

Для десериализации у меня есть классы:
1) InfoAccount, который который содержит поля Data и Status, и сеттеры/геттеры.
2) Data, с которым у меня и возникли проблемы:

```
package osip_000.mystats.json.info_account;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import osip_000.mystats.RetrofitApp;

public class AccountData {

    @SerializedName("453608")
    @Expose
    private Player Player;

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return Player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player Player) {
        this.Player = Player;
    }

}
```

Дело в том, что в ответе от сервера, id ("453608") может меняться (в зависимости от того, статистику какого игрока мы ищем (вводится никнейм в EditText в главном activity приложения)). Как я могу динамически изменять атрибут value для аннотации @SerializedName?

Пробовал в классе RetrofitApp сетить переменную accountId:

```
public class RetrofitApp extends Application {

    private static API wgAPI;
    private static String accountId;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.worldoftanks.ru/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        wgAPI = retrofit.create(API.class);
    }

    public static API getWgAPI() {
        return wgAPI;
    }

    public static void setAccountId(String newAccountId) {
        accountId = newAccountId;
    }

    public static String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }


}
```

И потом уже ее использовать в классе AccountData для динамического изменения ID:

```
//ДАННЫЙ КОД НЕПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ    
public class AccountData {

        private statis final String id = RetrofitApp.getAccountId();

        @SerializedName(id)
        @Expose
        private Player Player;

        public Player getPlayer() {
            return Player;
        }

        public void setPlayer(Player Player) {
            this.Player = Player;
        }
    }
```

Но, данное решение оказалось неверным, т.к. атрибут value должен быть константным выражением (Сообщение в IDE: Attribute value must be constant).

Подскажите, как я могу динамически изменять данный атрибут, или может есть другой способ, который позволит парсить JSON с различными ID?

Comment: Используйте для десериализации HashMap<Integer, Player>

Comment: @rjhdby , зачем и каким образом это повлияет на аннотацию @SerializedName?

Comment: Затем, что там у вас классический Map, хоть и с одним элементом

Comment: @rjhdby , все, понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@SerializedName("data")
private HashMap<Integer, Player> data;
```